# filling in struct values from char arrays

Tags: c

So I have filled arrays, and I need to assign them to their respective struct fields.

```
char array1[MaxLine] = "bob";
char array2[MaxLine] = "rick";
char array3[MaxLine] = "dan";
```

So lets just pretend that's what they say. I have a struct declared in a headerfile, and this function is in a second source, seperate from the main. How would I access the struct from this seperate function, in order to fill the values from those arrays.

Adding this in:

I have tried declaring a variable called filler..

```
struct structname filler;
```

and then using that to access the struct and fill it in this way..

```
strcpy(filler->firstfield, input);
strcpy(filler->secondfield, input);
```

but it keeps throwing an access violation.

Comment: @chrk edited it in, sorry.

Comment: you cannot use `->` on a struct, check the compiler messages.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more urgently please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you've included in the question so far is anything but an MCVE.  There is an awful lot of important information missing, and any one of those missing parts could contain the source of your trouble.  In general terms, using `strcpy()` to copy the fixed data into appropriately sized arrays in a structure should be fine.  If they're pointers, not arrays, in the structure, then you need to allocate memory before copying.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it in as an argument. For example:

```
#include "MyStruct.h" //declares the struct
#include "MyFunctions.h" // where the function is

int main()
{
   struct MyStruct instance;

   assignFields(&instance);

   //instance is now assigned
}

//In MyFunctions.h you declare your function
#include "MyStruct.h" //Needs to know about the struct
void assignField(MyStruct*);


//Then you implement it in the .c file
void assignFields(MyStruct* localInstance)
{
   //call strcpy here
   //assuming the input strings are available her
   //otherwise you have to pass them in as well

}
```

When you run the compiler, it will use the .h files to figure out the signatures and compile each file separately, then the linker will put the two .c files together in one executable program.